# Xcode simulator text field invisible when vertical

Tags: xcode

I'm just trying out the FoodTracker tutorial on Apple's website.

I just added a text field, label, and button. In the Assistant Editor everything looks fine vertically and horizontally. But in the iPhone 6 simulator, the text field is not showing up when it is vertical. When it's horizontal, it shows up and functions normally.

Comment: This is very probably an autolayout issue. 
Try to anchor the label and see if it solves the problem.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints

Comment: you can test your layout by selecting Debug>View Debugging>Capture View Hierarchy. Xcode loads the bounds of all views and you can find out, where your text field is located.

Comment: I deleted the constraints and remade them and it is working now. Should I just delete this question? Seems dumb now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints rendered it outside of the screen , remove them and redo the desired layout step by step to find out which constraint was it